# Stuck on fun math problem

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics

When I was preparing earlier this year for math competitions, I pooled a bunch of problems from different resources to practice with. I didn't complete all of them, and I decided to go back to them during my spring break, which recently started. On a one very fun problem, I made some progress but then got stuck and was wondering if someone could help me figure it out.

Here it is:

"What are the real-number solutions to the following system of equations?

$$
\begin{cases}
(2m - \frac{1}{m})np = n+p \\ 
(3n - \frac{1}{n})mp = p+m \\ 
(2020p - \frac{1}{p})mn = m+n \\ 
\end{cases}
$$
My approach:

1. I noticed some things (i.e. the symmetry).
2. I added the equations and then multiplied both sides by mnp.
3. I got 
   $$2025(mnp)^2-(m^2n^2 + m^2p^2 + n^2p^2) = 2m^2np + 2mn^2p + 2mnp^2$$
4. I thought of Vieta's formulas.
5. I realized that I can rewrite this as $2025(mnp)^2=(mn+mp+np)^2$.
6. I rewrote this as $45|mnp| = |mn+mp+np|$.
7. I separated this into 2 cases: $45mnp = mn+mp+np$ and $-45mnp = mn+mp+np$.
8. I thought of using Vieta's formulas by taking a polynomial $P(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + c$. Using Vieta's, this would give $b = 45c$ or $b = -45c$.

Then I got stuck.
I would really appreciate any help with this! I have spent a while trying to figure this problem out, and I can't get it off my mind.

Comment: Does the first equation start with $2m-\frac 1m$ or $\frac {2m-1}m$?  You wrote the first but I suspect you mean the second.  Why are the variables after the right parenthesis italicized?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. Your question has a good amount of context, and you can improve your post by learning [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/). It would also help if you don't write 'please help!' in the title.

Comment: @RossMillikan, it starts with 2m−1/m. Thanks! (The italics were unintentional, sorry!)

Comment: @TobyMak, thanks for the tips!

Comment: Sorry, I know this belongs in a comment, but I don't yet have a high enough Math StackExchange reputation to comment! Anyway, sorry if this is a dumb question, but I don't really understand from WhatsUp's answer how one would proceed. Update: Never mind, sorry, I get it now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will only talk about the case when all three of them are nonzero. The remaining case (i.e. at least one of them is zero) is left to you.

Assume that $m, n, p$ are all nonzero. We rewrite the first equation as: $$2m - 1/m = (n + p)/np = 1/n + 1/p,$$ and therefore $$1/m + 1/n + 1/p = 2m.$$

Similarly, the other two equations give $$1/m + 1/n + 1/p = 3n,$$$$1/m + 1/n + 1/p = 2020p.$$

From here it should be clear how to proceed.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help!